# Certain C code not displaying output in VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

So basically, I have this simple Hello World program and when executed, it outputs correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello");
}
```

```
Output: Hello
```

But for some reason adding a scanf command will cause the program to not output anything. It will display that it's running but it won't display anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int num1;

int main(){
    printf("Enter number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("%d", num1);
}
```

Output:

```
[Running] cd "d:\programming\" && gcc main.c -o main && "d:\programming\"main
```

I know my code is okay since I tried it on other IDEs and it worked correctly. I even copied code from the internet and tried to run in VSCode but it still didn't work. It still works perfectly fine yesterday but this problem just pops in nowhere.

I use Visual Studio Code 1.62.3 with C/C++, C/C++ Compile Run, and Code Runner extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a *buffering* problem. When standard output (`stdout`, where `printf` writes) is connected to an actual terminal then it's *line-buffered*, which means output is actually written to the terminal when there's a newline.

However, VSCode probably uses its own terminal emulation and uses *pipes* to connect `stdout` to that terminal. That means the output will be *fully* buffered, and you need to explicitly flush it.

So modify the code as such:

```
printf("Enter number: \n");
fflush(stdout);  // Actually write the output to standard output
scanf("%d", &num1);
printf("%d", num1);
```

That it works for the first example is because then the process terminates, and all output is flushed automatically.

Comment: It worked, thanks! @Some programmer dude Although I don't include this ```fflush(stdout);``` before and it still works. For some reason this problem just came up just a while ago. Do I need to insert this only once?